# Parallel in Perl for a related serial jobs

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I had a perl script to implement a serial jobs that the following job taking previous job's output. I am wondering if I can implement it in parallel? Which module should I use? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you cannot turn something that requires serial execution magically into parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said thus far I really don't know if this will help you, but just for the sake of trying this documentation can at least provide information on how you would have communication between your processes:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html

Furthermore, if you're starting to create parallel Perl software, making sure that you know event driven programming can be very helpful. Here is the AnyEvent module that makes event driven programming very slick and simple:

https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent

But more to your point about suggesting modules for parallel jobs, AnyEvent has a simple wrapper around fork() which could also be useful to your cause. This is the module that specifically deals with getting information back from "children":

[https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::Fork::RPC](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aFork%3a%3aRPC)

If none of that is actually helpful and you just are looking for some simple steps into parallel software writing, this module makes that easy:

[https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel%3a%3aSimple)